# The url-pattern WSATCoordinator in web application is mapped to multiple Servlets

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I installed the weblogic 12.2.1. i.e latest version and getting below error

```
<May 10, 2016 10:21:05 PM IST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initia
lize the application "my-app-Snapshot" due to error web
logic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.management.DeploymentException: [HTT
P:101401]The url-pattern WSATCoordinator in web application my-app-Snapshot.war is mapped to multiple Servlets.
weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.management.DeploymentException: [
HTTP:101401]The url-pattern WSATCoordinator in web application my-app-Snapshot.war is mapped to multiple Servlets.
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(Extensi
bleModuleWrapper.java:114)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(Modu
leListenerInvoker.java:100)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleSta
teDriver.java:196)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleSta
teDriver.java:191)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(Stat
eMachineDriver.java:83)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.management.DeploymentException: [HTTP:101401]The url-pattern
 WSATCoordinator in web application my-app-Snapshot.war
 is mapped to multiple Servlets.
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.logAndThrowDeploymentE
xception(WebAppServletContext.java:1299)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.registerServletMapping
(WebAppServletContext.java:1620)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.registerServletMapping
s(WebAppServletContext.java:1497)
```

I see one issue related to it i.e. https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/OPENAM-7947/OPENAM-7947.html but that is marked not reproducible. Any idea whats the issue?

same war file working fine on tomcat

Answer (score 0):

If you use web annotations in java code, you don't have to declare the servlet in the web.xml file any more.

You can try by removing the corresponding "servlet" and "servlet-mapping" tags in web.xml

It seems that WebLogic 12.1.3 can deal with double declaration (inline annotation & xml) but not anymore in WebLogic 12.2.

I had this error with @webservice annotation when I specified the "serviceName" parameter and when I declared the servlet in web.xml file with the same value.